# SelectBox does not show me the data transferred from ViewData dictionary

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, selectlist, viewdata

I'm trying to show my data received from `ViewData["ProductGroupId"]` and `ViewData["ProductSubGroupId"]` in two seperate drop down lists.
When debbuging, everything is ok and I can see that my data are correctly fetched from the database, but when I run the application, I see that my drop down lists are empty! like bellow:
[image]

My code inside the `controller`:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var groups = _productServices.GetGroupsListItem();
    var subGroups = _productServices.GetSubGroups_ByGroupId_ListItem(int.Parse(groups.First().Value));
    ViewData["ProductGroupId"] = new SelectList(groups.ToList(), "Value", "Text");
    ViewData["ProductSubGroupId"] = new SelectList(subGroups.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

    return View();
}
```

My `View Razore` is:

```
@model Keyhanatr.Data.Domain.Products.Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ایجاد محصول";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="col-lg-12 pt-lg-4 pb-4 mb-3">
        <div class="pt-2 px-4 ps-lg-0 pe-xl-5">

            -->
            Title
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center pb-2">
                <h2 class="h3 py-2 me-2 text-center text-sm-start">درج محصول جدید</h2>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ProductGroupId"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ProductGroupId" class="form-select me-2" asp-items="@(ViewBag.ProductGroupId as SelectList)"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ProductSubGroupId"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ProductSubGroupId" class="form-select me-2" asp-items="@(ViewData["ProductSubGroupId"] as SelectList)"> </select>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 pb-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-name">نام محصول</label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ProductTitle" id="unp-product-name">
                <div class="form-text">حداکثر 100 حرف هیچ L یا شکلک مجاز نیست.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="file-drop-area mb-3">
                <div class="file-drop-icon ci-cloud-upload"></div><span class="file-drop-message">برای بارگذاری تصویر صفحه از محصول ، آن را بکشید و رها کنید</span>
                <input class="file-drop-input" type="file" name="imgUp">
                <button class="file-drop-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-2" type="button">یا پرونده را انتخاب کنید</button>
                <div class="form-text">1000 x 800px اندازه ایده آل برای نمایشگرهای با وضوح بالا</div>
            </div>
            @if (ViewBag.IsNullImg != null)
            {
                <div class="form-text text-danger"><span>لطفا یک تصویر را برای محصول انتخاب کنید</span></div>
            }
            <div class="mb-3 py-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-description">توضیحات محصول</label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control" rows="6" id="unp-product-description"></textarea>
                <div class="bg-secondary p-3 fs-ms rounded-bottom"><span class="d-inline-block fw-medium me-2 my-1">پشتیبانی می کند:</span><em class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">*کج*</em><strong class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">**برجسته**</strong><span class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">- لیست</span><span class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">##سربرگ##</span><span class="d-inline-block">--- افقی</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="unp-standard-price">قیمت استاندارد</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="unp-standard-price">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-text">قیمت محصول بر حسب تومان اعمال خواهد شد.</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 py-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-tags">برچسب های محصول</label>
                <textarea placeholder="عطرمردانه-جدید-اسپرت" class="form-control" rows="4" id="unp-product-tags"></textarea>
                <div class="form-text">حداکثر 10 کلمه کلیدی که مورد شما را توصیف می کنند. همه برچسب ها باید با حروف کوچک و با خط فاصله یا همان (-) از هم جدا شوند.</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit"><i class="ci-cloud-upload fs-lg me-2"></i>آپلود محصول</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

For `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);`, the first parameter is the source, the second parameter is each option value in select, the third parameter is that each option displays text in html. **The second and third parameter should be the property in your source.**

So you need to be sure the `Text` and `Value` are the property in your `groups` and `subGroups`.

Here is a simple demo:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
    public int ProductSubGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class SubGroup
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ایجاد محصول";
}
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="col-lg-12 pt-lg-4 pb-4 mb-3">
        <div class="pt-2 px-4 ps-lg-0 pe-xl-5">    
            -->
            Title
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center pb-2">
                <h2 class="h3 py-2 me-2 text-center text-sm-start">درج محصول جدید</h2>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ProductGroupId"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ProductGroupId" class="form-select me-2" asp-items="@(ViewBag.ProductGroupId as SelectList)"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ProductSubGroupId"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ProductSubGroupId" class="form-select me-2" asp-items="@(ViewData["ProductSubGroupId"] as SelectList)"> </select>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 pb-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-name">نام محصول</label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ProductTitle" id="unp-product-name">
                <div class="form-text">حداکثر 100 حرف هیچ L یا شکلک مجاز نیست.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="file-drop-area mb-3">
                <div class="file-drop-icon ci-cloud-upload"></div><span class="file-drop-message">برای بارگذاری تصویر صفحه از محصول ، آن را بکشید و رها کنید</span>
                <input class="file-drop-input" type="file" name="imgUp">
                <button class="file-drop-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-2" type="button">یا پرونده را انتخاب کنید</button>
                <div class="form-text">1000 x 800px اندازه ایده آل برای نمایشگرهای با وضوح بالا</div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="mb-3 py-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-description">توضیحات محصول</label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control" rows="6" id="unp-product-description"></textarea>
                <div class="bg-secondary p-3 fs-ms rounded-bottom"><span class="d-inline-block fw-medium me-2 my-1">پشتیبانی می کند:</span><em class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">*کج*</em><strong class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">**برجسته**</strong><span class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">- لیست</span><span class="d-inline-block border-end pe-2 me-2 my-1">##سربرگ##</span><span class="d-inline-block">--- افقی</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mb-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="unp-standard-price">قیمت استاندارد</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="unp-standard-price">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-text">قیمت محصول بر حسب تومان اعمال خواهد شد.</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 py-2">
                <label class="form-label" for="unp-product-tags">برچسب های محصول</label>
                <textarea placeholder="عطرمردانه-جدید-اسپرت" class="form-control" rows="4" id="unp-product-tags"></textarea>
                <div class="form-text">حداکثر 10 کلمه کلیدی که مورد شما را توصیف می کنند. همه برچسب ها باید با حروف کوچک و با خط فاصله یا همان (-) از هم جدا شوند.</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit"><i class="ci-cloud-upload fs-lg me-2"></i>آپلود محصول</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    //var groups = _productServices.GetGroupsListItem();
    //var subGroups = _productServices.GetSubGroups_ByGroupId_ListItem(int.Parse(groups.First().Value));
    //for easy testing, I just hard-coded here......
    var groups = new List<Group>()
    {
        new Group(){Id="1",Name="aa"},
        new Group(){Id="2",Name="bb"},
        new Group(){Id="3",Name="cc"}
    };
    var subGroups = new List<SubGroup>()
    {
        new SubGroup(){Id="1",SubName="SubA"},
        new SubGroup(){Id="2",SubName="SubB"},
        new SubGroup(){Id="3",SubName="SubC"}
    };
    ViewData["ProductGroupId"] = new SelectList(groups.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["ProductSubGroupId"] = new SelectList(subGroups.ToList(), "Id", "SubName");
    return View();

}
```

Result:

[image]